# Run hook_nodeapi("pre save") but only on inserts, not on updates

Tags: 6, hooks

For `hook_nodeapi()`, I want it to run on "presave," but only on inserts, not on updates. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can know if it an update or insert by looking the `$node->nid` value. If you've a number it's an update otherwise an insert.

You can see an example directly on the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6).